# Can an OData URL checking length be expressed using Breeze JS?

Tags: javascript, odata, breeze

I have been playing around with Breeze.js to fetch data from OData services. I could express most of the URLs in terms of breeze, but I am not able to find a way to express the following URL, it is based on length of a field:

```
http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$filter=length(CompanyName) eq 19
```

I am curious to know if there is a way to query the above OData URL using Breeze.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think that the following should work.

```
 var query = new EntityQuery()
        .from("Customers")
        .where("length(companyName)", "==", 19);
```

or

```
 var query = new EntityQuery()
        .from("Customers")
        .where("length(CompanyName)", "==", 19);
```

depending on your *breeze.NamingConvention* settings.

Comment: Thanks Jay, it worked. For URLs like http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$filter=not startswith(CompanyName,'P') eq true , do we need to create a predicate with startsWith and then apply the "not" predicate on it?

Comment: For "starts with" use var p = Predicate("companyName", "startsWith","P"); For "does not start with" use var p = Predicate("companyName", "startsWith", "P").not();

Comment: I meant the same, may be I didn't express it properly. Thanks again!